# Larval left join with Eloquent causing id field to be overwritten

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am building search listings application using Laravel; the app needs to search for Businesses by distance (which I've already built) and include the latest subscription to a business (if any) so I can order by it and then distance.

The two models here are Business and Subscriptions. A Business can have many Subscriptions (although there will only ever be one thats active).

**Controller**

```
$businesses = Business::distance($place['lat'], $place['lng'], $request->distance)
                        ->ofShopType($request->shop_type)
                        ->uptoBudget($request->price)
                        ->leftJoin('subscriptions', function($join) {
                            $join->on('businesses.id', '=', 'subscriptions.business_id')
                                 ->orderBy('subscriptions.created_at', 'desc');
                        });
return $businesses = $businesses->get();
```

**Business Model**

```
public function scopeDistance($query,$from_latitude,$from_longitude,$distance)
{
    $raw = \DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$from_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ), 1 ) AS distance');
    return $query->select('*')->addSelect($raw)
             ->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' )
             ->groupBy('businesses.id')
             ->having('distance', '<=', $distance);
}
```

So the difficulties I am getting are that the `business.id` field is being overwritten by the `subscription.id`.
I've done some searching and have read that including `->select('businesses.*')` before the `leftJoin` should resolve this, however by doing this I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
      'business.distance' in 'having clause'
      (SQL: select `businesses`.*
          from `businesses`
          left join `subscriptions`
                   on `businesses`.`id` = `subscriptions`.`business_id`
          where `shop_type_id` = 1
            and `min_cost` <= 100
          group by `distance`, `businesses`.`id`
          having `distance` <= 50
          order by `distance` asc)
```

The second issue is that the left join seems to get the first record, I would like to get the most recent record (by `created_at`). You can see that I already have an `orderBy` line in my controller but this has no affect as I can see its still returning an older record even though a newer record is available.

Comment: Why are you grouping by `distance`?

Comment: This was a mistake, I've updated the query. The issue still occurs with distance field but in the having clause now.

Comment: <sarcasm>Sometimes it is easier to write SQL than to figure out how to create SQL using 3rd party software.</sarcasm>

Comment: @Imran Please add your tables on sql fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `->select('businesses.*')` in your controller you will will overwrite your select from `scopeDistance()`.
You should use the table alias in the scope function. I would also remove `groupBy()` from the scope function,
since it doesn't make sence there.
And it's better to remove `orderBy()` as well, because you can't overwrite it (easily) later.

```
public function scopeDistance($query,$from_latitude,$from_longitude,$distance)
{
    $raw = \DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$from_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ), 1 ) AS distance');
    return $query->select('businesses.*')->addSelect($raw)
        ->having('distance', '<=', $distance);
}
```

If you want to order the result by the last subscriptions creation time, you will need to order using an aggregate function.
In your case it should be `ORDER BY MAX(subscriptions.created_at) DESC`. Also here is the right place to GROUP BY `business.id`.
And it doesn't make sence to use `ORDER BY` in the JOIN clause.
I'd expect to get an exception, because I don't know how that could be translated to a valid SQL expression.
But it seems that laravel is just ignoring it.
So the code in your controller could be:

```
$businesses = Business::distance($place['lat'], $place['lng'], $request->distance)
    ->ofShopType($request->shop_type)
    ->uptoBudget($request->price)
    ->leftJoin('subscriptions', 'businesses.id', '=', 'subscriptions.business_id')
    ->groupBy('business.id')
    ->orderByRaw('max(subscriptions.created_at) DESC')
    ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');
return $businesses->get();
```

Comment: While this does return in the order I want, it doesn't include the matched subscription record. Could you add how include this?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that using `select('businesses.*')` will prevent the `id` field from being overwritten.

I would suggest using `selectRaw` as follows:

```
public function scopeDistance($query, $from_latitude, $from_longitude, $distance)
{
    $raw = \DB::raw('ROUND ( ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$from_longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$from_latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ), 1 ) AS distance');
    return $query->selectRaw("businesses.*, $raw")->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' )->groupBy('businesses.id')->having('distance', '<=', $distance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `lastSubscription()` relation to your `Business` model:

```
public function lastSubscription()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Subscription::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

Then in your controller you'd be able to do:

```
return Business::distance($place['lat'], $place['lng'], $request->distance)
                        ->ofShopType($request->shop_type)
                        ->uptoBudget($request->price)
                        ->with('lastSubscription')
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not re-assing the `$bussinesses` var and just return the result of the query.

```
return Business::distance($place['lat'], $place['lng'], $request->distance)
                        ->ofShopType($request->shop_type)
                        ->uptoBudget($request->price)
                        ->leftJoin('subscriptions', function($join) {
                            $join->on('businesses.id', '=', 'subscriptions.business_id')
                                 ->orderBy('subscriptions.created_at', 'desc');
                        })->get();
```